# How to get Alert Box in chrome using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome

```
package com.company;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.sql.SQLOutput;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

        public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Logan\\Downloads\\selenium-java-3.141.59\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        String msg = alert.getText();
```

I want to get Alert box when the window opens up . I've tried to delay the process using Thread.sleep but still it's not working .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `thread.sleep()`, you can invoke `WebDriverWait` on new `ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()` to ensure the alert is fully loaded before trying to call `alert.getText()`:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
// add the above import statements

// wait for alert to exist
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());

Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
String msg = alert.getText();
```

If this does not work for you, your browser may not be displaying a true alert -- you could try to inspect the popup and see if it has any HTML elements behind it to verify this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use explicit wait until the alert is present before switching to it. Try below code

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 40)
        .ignoring(NoAlertPresentException.class)
        .until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());

Alert al = driver.switchTo().alert();

String msg = al.getText();
```

Comment: You are sure it is alert box (web alert or window alert) or pop up?